# PHP foreach not looping

Tags: php, foreach

I'm new in programming and just started php like two months ago. So far I seemed to understand it more and more. But now I am stumped. I have a foreach loop that won't loop through the array I'm feeding it. I have checked the syntax and logic over and over again and can't find the problem. I'm probably doing something stupid, but I need your help finding out what it is.

This code is part of a script to allow a logged-in user to change his personal information. I put the data from `$_POST` in an array and feed it (with the `session_user_id`) to my function `wijzig_gegevens()`:

```
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
$gegevens = array(
    'voornaam' => $_POST['voornaam'],
    'achternaam' => $_POST['achternaam'],
    'emailadres' => $_POST['emailadres']
);
wijzig_gegevens($session_gebruiker_id, $gegevens);
}
```

I have checked if `$gegevens` is actually an array and it is; when I `print_r($gegevens)` I get the following output (this is an associative array, right?):

```
Array ( [voornaam] => Marieke [achternaam] => Schut [emailadres] => mariekeschut@gmail.com )
```

So the information is sent to my function `wijzig_gegevens()`. When I make `wijzig_gegevens()` return `$gegevens` and my primary code `print_r(wijzig_gegevens())`, it shows the exact same array as above. So `$gegevens` arrives in `wijzig_gegevens()` and is still an array.

So then the `wijzig_gegevens()` should do its part. Eventually it should update the database, but for now I/m just trying to get it to produce the key/value pairs from the array. Here's the function:

```
function wijzig_gegevens($gebruiker_id, $gegevens) {
    global $db;
    $gebruiker_id = (int)$gebruiker_id;
    foreach($gegevens as $key => $value) {
    return $key.$value;
    }
}
```

I expected the `foreach` to display 3 sets of key/value pairs. But for some reason it only displays the first key/value pair:

```
voornaamMarieke
```

This has been puzzling me for over a day now, so I'm hoping someone can help me find my mistake.

Comment: You've got a `return` within a loop. When it hits the `return`, that's it. The function call is over. Instead of  `return`, you could use `echo`. But you shouldn't really `echo` from a function (depending). So you could concatenate to a variable and return is *after* the `foreach` loop.

Comment: You should really code in english lol :D

Comment: Great job on stating the problem and your observations very clearly.

Comment: I want to ask how you are developing your code. Are you just using an editor, or are you using an IDE? [Print debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging) does work, but it not the proper way to go about it. Get yourself a good IDE (for instance  [Eclipse PDT](https://eclipse.org/pdt/)) and learn how to set a breakpoint and evaluate variables, without changing your code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just return first value of loop in your code .You need an array to store whole key value of foreach loop as

```
$array=array();// define your array
foreach($gegevens as $key => $value) {
     $array[]=$key.$value;
}
return $array;// return array
```

And you get your return value as

```
$data=wijzig_gegevens($session_gebruiker_id, $gegevens);
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

easy and simple, return only returns a value therefore to get all values without writing much code use echo instead of return

```
$array=array();// define your array
foreach($gegevens as $key) {
     $array[]=$key;
}
echo $array;// return array
```

Comment: This answer is a near-duplicate to the accepted answer 5 years ago.